# PHP Return Correct Time

Tags: php, time

For the life of me I can't figure out how to return the current time in PHP correctly.  First let me show you the setup.

Server local time is in CST

I am in PST so there is a 2 hour difference.  I also put in the htaccess of my server the following statement:

SetEnv TZ Amercia/Los_Angeles

Ok and my PHP statement to pull the current time is

```
<?php $t = time(); echo(date("D F d Y H:i:s",$t)); ?>
```

But this code seem to return 8 hours ahead...I can't figure out why?? I want it to return my PST time...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function in your script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

[List of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 3):

The `time` function returns universal time (UTC). If you want the local time, use `localtime`.

Comment: `localtime` takes the same `time` function as its first param. Why would `date` and `localtime` return different results as they're both affected by the set timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a bootstrap type file...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Amercia/Los_Angeles');
```

You also don't need to pass `$t` to the `date()` function, by default it will use the current `time()`.